# sIFR 3.0 and sWmode

Tags: flash, sifr

Previous versions of sIFR allowed users to enter "sWmode: 'transparent'" to avoid the common problem of Flash objects being overlayed on regular HTML objects on screen, no matter the z-index of either elements.

How do I replicate this behavior in sIFR 3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you can use

```
wmode: 'transparent'
```

or

```
wmode: 'opaque'
```

But also

```
transparent: true
```

or

```
opaque: true
```

Whatever floats your boat :)

Do note that browsers usually have issues with transparent Flash movies, so usually specifying a background color is the better option.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I appreciate the response.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to add:

```
wmode: 'transparent'
```

in the object you send into sIFR.replace()

Answer (score 0):

The expressions will not be interpreted all the same way. E.g. in Chrome 10 `wmode: 'transparent'` will cause a black background behind the replaced text, while `wmode: 'opaque'` works like it should. Strange!